# Why don't I have to escape equal sign?

Tags: javascript, regex

For example:

```
"1+1=2".replace(/=/,"aa");
"1+1=2".replace(/\=/,"aa");
```

return the same result.

Does it mean I don't have to escape "=" (the equal sign) in JavaScript? I remembered that I always have to escape equal sign in Java and .NET.

I tried to find some info from https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html but didn't come up with anything.

Can anyone help me find if the specification talks about escaping the equal sign?

Comment: `=` has no special meaning in regular expressions, it doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: They don't escape it in Java in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274303/regular-expression-with-an-and-a)

Comment: And here's a .net question that doesn't escape it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490169/lookbehind-with-equal-sign

Comment: @Barmar how would you explain the usage of = in Positive lookahead `(?= )`? I thought = is then a special character that always needs to be escaped..

Comment: Lots of characters have special meaning after `(?`, but they don't have special meaning elsewhere, so they don't need to be escaped.

Comment: What's really going on is that `(?` is special, and it uses the next character as a dispatch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go with [this table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_special_characters) in MDN web docs. You'll see that `=` has no special meaning - just as @Barmar stated. You referred to [lookaheads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-lookahead), which use `?=`, but without the leading `?` it's just an equal sign.

There are not many special characters which needs an additional special character to "work", I guess that's why it's confusing. Think of it as `-` in combination with `[` and `]`:

- `0-9` matches "0-9"
- `[0-9]` matches "0" **and** "1" **and** ... **and** "9"
- `[0\-9]` matches "0" and "1" and ... and "9" **and "-"**

So just `-` has no meaning and does not have to be escaped, only if combined with square brackets. The same applies to `=` with/without `?`.